# C99: right way to initialize _complex variable with (+0 -0.0i)

Tags: c99, complex-numbers

What is the right way to statically initialize `float _complex` variable with `(+0 -0.0i)` (positive zero in real and negative zero in imag) in C99?

```
float _Complex a = _Complex_I * (-0.0); // this seems doesn't work
int main()
{
    printf("a = (%f %f) \t(0x%016llx)\n",crealf(a),cimagf(a), *((long long*)&a));
}
```

PS. I need a static initialization, so this can't be used

```
  __real__ a = 0.0; __imag__ a = 0.0;
```

Comment: Document from ISO C working group: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1464.htm - CMPLX is added in C1x aka C11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there really isn't one.  This is why the C standard includes the `CMPLX` macros in C1x.

Since I believe that you're using GCC, you may be interested in following [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48760).  In particular, if you don't mind living on the bleeding edge, you may be able to do something like:

```
float _Complex a = { 0.0f, -0.0f };
```

(see discussion around Jason Merrill's commit on April 28 for more details).  I'm not certain, but you may also need to file a separate bug requesting support for this feature in the C front end.

Comment: What is minimal gcc version for `{}`-styled complex initialization? I can't do this on 4.5.2

Comment: @osgx: since it appears to have been checked in on April 28th, probably 4.6.x or 4.7.  There's no good answer right now.  Do file a bug asking that it be supported in the front-end.